# Session not saving in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

ok, so I'm trying to store a session at Login when someone Logs in. I'm storing the session, saving it, but at the next page, I can't retrieve that session. It's a null output. The storage folder is set to 775, so I don't see why it wouldn't be writing. Auth session get's wrote btw, it's just the Session::put() keys that aren't being stored. Below is the code:

**LoginController.php**

```
if(Auth::attempt(['username' => $this->user, 'password' => $inp->password, 'Login' => $this->acct]))
        {
            # [2]: If TRUE, Create sessions, redirect
            $authArr = SubUsers::join('sub_services as ss', 'sub_users.userid', '=', 'ss.userid')->where('sub_users.username', $this->user)->first()->toArray();

            // Create The Sessions
            Session::put('Username', $this->user);  # constant | User that's currently logged in
            Session::put('Account', $this->acct);   # changing | Account Data being passed to view
            Session::save();

            Session::push('Auth', $authArr);

            // Redirect
            if(Session::has('lasturl')){
                $lasturl = Session::get('lasturl');
                return Redirect::to($lasturl);
            }
            else { return Redirect::to($this->startScreen); }
        }
```

**BaseAppController.php**

```
public function __construct()
{
    dd(Session::has('Username')); # [ This Returns Null ]
}
```

UPDATE:
Below is the session getting stored in the storage/framework/sessions folder. It's being stored correct:

```
a:8:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"dEf3bJ4vz9fjiUuVnjD5EKNIKgJ38UzgZ0q4aE7K";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:43:"http://localhost:8888/alpha/public/settings";}s:5:"flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}s:38:"login_82e5d2c56bdd0811318f0cf078b78bfc";i:78;s:8:"Username";s:4:"demo";s:7:"Account";s:4:"demo";s:4:"Auth";a:1:{i:0;a:20:{s:6:"userid";i:78;s:7:"groupid";N;s:5:"Login";s:4:"demo";s:8:"username";s:4:"demo";s:8:"password";s:60:"$2y$10$9Q1/zGeRrrDwl2rfjmkIWuWv3V/LpgFVYR/68PjANCsIkKmIVRVAu";s:4:"name";s:11:"John Babtis";s:5:"email";s:16:"jo@relatient.net";s:14:"remember_token";s:60:"2dqaWk56uJ1ldTdHhLcGg5U47JGxAD7EKdqwlr5qpPMGat9BKpMTf8tDtUlL";s:13:"userserviceid";i:81;s:9:"SuperUser";i:1;s:13:"MasterAccount";i:1;s:14:"canCreateUsers";i:1;s:12:"canEditUsers";i:1;s:2:"hm";i:1;s:6:"demand";i:1;s:9:"pophealth";i:1;s:12:"appointments";i:1;s:7:"reports";i:1;s:8:"settings";i:1;s:12:"canEditChild";i:1;}}s:9:"_sf2_meta";a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1437755751;s:1:"c";i:1437755740;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}}
```

Comment: try `dd`ing the session out right after you save it to make sure the values you are storing aren't `null`.

Comment: There storing. The dump shows that. It's also showing a value right after storing it. it's when it redirects the page is when the session pulls null.

Comment: For ease it's this section in the dump: s:8:"Username";s:4:"demo";s:7:"Account";s:4:"demo";

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-creates-a-new-session-after-each-request

Comment: @Alexander. Wasn't the problem. For some reason, PHP / Laravel was case sensative to "Username". Once I renamed it to "username", all worked. It's magic in my eyes because I don't think PHP uses that term. The only reason I can see why it wouldn't have worked is if Auth service provider was possibly rewriting the session variable?

Comment: You could be right about something rewriting the variable. Was Account being read correctly? If it doesn't work either it could be a bug in Laravel.

Comment: And it would have had to be something in Laravel not PHP directly. Laravel uses file storage for sessions by default (unlike PHP's superglobal `$_SESSION`)

Comment: @Alexander : Yes, both "Account" and "Auth" has been and is still pulling correct. It was only the "Username" session that was pulling null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, `username` all lowercase. Remember, PHP is case sensitive.

Comment: I'm storing the key as 'Username' though. Infact, check my edit out, it has a dump of the session getting written to the storage/framework/sessions folder

Comment: Try saving it in lowercase.

Comment: that won't help at all... he is using the exact keyname in both places.

Comment: Why it did I have absolutely no clue. Is Username a global variable in Laravel or PHP? I really would like an explanation of this magic. :)

Comment: Is the reason behind this something to do with the Auth provider / facade? Could it possibly have been rewriting the Username session? I just don't see the PHP language using that as a term or global variable.

Answer (score 0):

So to give a more accurate answer to **navasd** answer, Username was getting overwritten by the `Guard.php` in the `Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php` file.

It stores sessions by name and for some reason it was storing the Username as null and overwriting my `Session::put('Username')` session variable. Renaming it to 'username' has worked though.