# Facebook login in laravel 5.2 can't hold the session after redirect

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook PHP SDK to log my user.

I created a guard called login for this

**Here is my config file of auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin'=>[
        'driver'=>'session',
        'provider'=>'adminusers',
    ],
    'verify'=>[
        'driver'=>'session',
        'provider'=>'verify',
    ],
    'login'=>[
        'driver'=>'session',
        'provider'=>'users'
    ]
],
```

to access Facebook api i created a class in App\services namespace called it Facebook

**App\Services\Facbook.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

use App\Extensions\Facebook\FacebookLaravelPersistentDataHandler; 
use Facebook\Facebook as FB;
use App;

class Facebook{

protected $fb;

protected $helper;

protected $permission;

protected $log;

protected $canvashelper;

protected $persistentDataHandler;

function __construct()
{
    $this->fb   =   new FB([
                    'app_id'=>Config::get('facebook.app_id'),
                    'app_secret'=>Config::get('facebook.app_secret'),
                    'default_graph_version' => Config::get('facebook.default_graph_version'),
                    'persistent_data_handler' => new FacebookLaravelPersistentDataHandler(),
                    ]);

    $this->helper = $this->fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

    $this->permission = Config::get('facebook.permission');

    $this->log = new Logging(Config::get('facebook.logfile'),'Facebook Log');

    $this->canvashelper =   $this->fb->getCanvasHelper();

    $this->persistentDataHandler = new FacebookLaravelPersistentDataHandler();
}

public function FBAuthUrl()
{
    if($this->isFBAuth())
    {
        return $this->helper->getLogoutUrl($this->persistentDataHandler->get('facebook_access_token'),route('facebook.logout'));
    }
    else
    {
        return $this->helper->getLoginUrl(route('facebook.callback'),$this->permission);
    }
}

public function LoginCallback()
{           
    $accessToken = $this->helper->getAccessToken(); 
    if(isset($accessToken))
    {   
        $this->persistentDataHandler->set('facebook_access_token',(string) $accessToken);
    }

}

public function isFBAuth()
{
    return $this->persistentDataHandler->has('facebook_access_token');
}

public function getFBUser()
{
    if($this->isFBAuth())
    {
        $this->fb->setDefaultAccessToken($this->persistentDataHandler->get('facebook_access_token'));
        /*,user_birthday,user_tagged_places*/
        $response = $this->fb->get("/me?fields=id,name,first_name,last_name,age_range,link,gender,locale,picture,timezone,updated_time,verified,email");
        return $response->getGraphUser();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    $this->persistentDataHandler->delete('facebook_access_token');
    $this->persistentDataHandler->delete('state');
}

}
```

And Here is my UserController Where i write my login logic

```
    class UserController extends Controller
{
    .....
/*
 * Facebook login callback function
 * @param Object App\services\Facebook
 * return redirect
 */

public function fbLogin(Facebook $facebook)
{
    $facebook->LoginCallback();

    /*
     * get the usergraphnode from facebook
     */
    $fbUser = $facebook->getFBUser();

    /*
     * Convert UserGraphNode User To Eloquent User
     */
    $user = $this->getFBLoggedUser($fbUser);        

    /*
     * Here Log the user in laravel System
     */
    Auth::guard('login')->login($user);
    //dump(Auth::guard($this->guard)->user());
    dump(session()->all());
    return reidrect('/');
}


public function getFBLoggedUser($fbUser)
{
    if(User::where('email','=',$fbUser->getField('email'))->count())
    {
        $user = User::where('email','=',$fbUser->getField('email'))->first();
        if($user->fb_app_id){
            $user->fb_app_id = $fbUser->getField('id');
            $user->save();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $user = $this->FBregister($fbUser);
    }
    return $user;
}


/**
 * Register The user logged in from Facebook
 *
 * @param \Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser;
 * 
 * return  \App\Models\User
 */
public function FBregister($fbUser)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->fname = $fbUser->getField('first_name');
    $user->lname = $fbUser->getField('last_name');
    $user->gender = $fbUser->getField('gender');
    $user->email = $fbUser->getField('email');
    $user->fb_app_id = $fbUser->getField('id');

    $picture = $fbUser->getField('picture');
    if($picture->isSilhouette()){
        $user->profile_image = $picture->getUrl();
    }

    $user->save();

    return $user;
}

.........
}
```

On Successful Facebook login redirect i am calling UserController@fbLogin
after calling `Auth::guard()->login()` i dump session it successfully show a `login_login_randomstring=>UserId` i session . but When i redirect it all session data lost.

But the weird thing is that it only happen when it calling through facebook redirect. If i use this function like normal login routes it works perfactaly like this

**in route.php**

```
Route::get('/login','UserController@login');
```

**and in UserController**

```
function login(){
 $user = User::find(12);
 Auth::guard('login')->login($user);
 return redirect('/');
}
```

Using this method i can easily access Session data after redirecting from here but in facebook case it doesn't happening.

I stuck here for two days please anyone can help me

***[Note: Please don't mention in your answer that i should grouped my routes in web middleware.  ]***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After digging very deep in laravel i finally found what i was doing wrong. And i am posting may be it help some in future.

Important thing :- Laravel save session very last in its request life-cycle. It saves session it sends header response. So if we echo something in controller class then it will send header response without doing saving session and our session will not save. In my case i use `dump` function in my controller which terminate the laravel default life-cycle and forcefully send header response to browser. that's why all of session data is lost. i remove `dump()` form my code and everything start working correctly

Answer (score 5):

According to API documentation `https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Auth/Guard.html` you should call `user()` method to get the currently authenticated user. So i would suggest that instead of `Auth::guard()` use `Auth::user($user)`.

Comment: I think you didn't read full question i say i lost my session data after successfully authenticating and then  redirect user to another page. Getting authenticated user is not my problem at all.

Comment: Can you please check how you give the 777 permisions to file in storage folder?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615462/session-not-saving-in-laravel-5-1

Answer (score 4):

try to use plugin socialite for login with facebook [socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite)

Facebook php sdk use $_SESSION.In laravel you cannot access this variable,laravel use personal class for session.

Comment: I know that very well that's why i added a custom presistent data handler class `App\Extensions\Facebook\FacebookLaravelPersistentDataHandler` which is responsible to write data into session. About using Socialite, It is a good plugin but we only can get very basic services from facebook with that.

Comment: and i found why session lost its data, check my answer

Answer (score 2):

According to api code and your facebook documentation. Simple session working with request. You can save your data with

For put session in value

```
Session::put('userid','1');
```

Retrieve the value

```
$request->session()->get('userid')  //or
   {!! Session::get('userid') !!}
```

Very useful thing in your case.

Comment: thanks for your answer but this was not my problem. I explain my problem's answer with detail in my answer. See my answer